# How to use 24 hour time series data as a predictive feature

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, time-series, data-analysis

I am just wondering how best to approach using this 24 hour time format as a predictive feature. My thoughts were to bin it into 24 categories for each hour of the day. Is there an easy way to convert this object into a python datetime object that would make binning easier or how would you advise handling this feature? Thanks :)

```
df['Duration']

0         2:50
1         7:25
2        19:00
3         5:25
4         4:45
5         2:25

df['Duration'].dtype

dtype('O')
```

Comment: If you only care about the hour, try splitting on the colon: `df.Duration.str.split(':').str[0]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution will depend on what you hope to get from your model.  In many cases it makes sense to convert it to total number of seconds (or minutes or hours) since some epoch. To convert your data to seconds since 00:00, you can use:

```
from datetime import datetime

t_str = "2:50"

t_delta = datetime.strptime(t_str, "%H:%M") - datetime(1900, 1, 1)
seconds = t_delta.total_seconds()
hours = seconds/60**2

print(seconds)
# 10200.0
```

Using Python's `datetime` class will not support time values over 23:59.  Since it appears that your data may actually be a duration, you may want to represent it as an instance of Python's `timedelta` class.

```
from datetime import timedelta  

h, m = map(int, t_str.split(sep=':'))
t_delta = timedelta(hours=h, minutes=m)

# Get total number of seconds
seconds = t_delta.total_seconds()
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm now getting the error: ValueError: time data '25:30' does not match format '%H:%M'. I guess I have some more cleaning to do...

Comment: The `%H` format specifier only accepts hour values between 0 and 23.  Depending on how reliable the format is, you can use something like `h, m = map(int, t_str.split(sep=':')); seconds = h*60**2 + m*60`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use datetime to create a useable datetime string

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> x = datetime(2019, 1, 1, 0).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
>>> # Use that for your timestring then you can reverse it nicely back into a datetime object
>>> d = datetime.strptime('2019-01-01 00:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Of course you can use any valid format string.

Answer (score 0):

You should calculate the time in seconds or minutes or hours from some initial time like the 1st time. Then you can make an x-y scatter plot of the data since the x-axis (time) is now numbers.